# MapKit with custom Maps

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, custom-controls, mapkit

For my next project I have an image of a small village and I have to turn this into a map. 
In this map I have to be able to add `MKAnnotationView` like the "normal" `MapKit` Map. The user can also zoom the map. I'm just trying to figure out how to implement this custom map: The only possible way is to create a `UIImageView` as subviews to which I add the "reproductions" of `MKAnnotationView`?

Any suggestions on how I can create this type of map?

Answer (score 2):

Also have a look at MapBox. There are two options:

1. [MapBox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk) - works like MapKit, but is an open source alternative that lets you do completely custom maps (iOS 5+).
2. [MBXMapKit](http://mapbox.com/mbxmapkit) - built on MapKit, but allows custom map tiles (iOS 7+).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using a UIImageView will work particularly well. If the suggested source code doesn't work for you, look at the documentation and sample code for [CATiledLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html).